# What do I do when I get "Cannot Connect to iTunes store" when downloading an app?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

I'm using an iPad 2, iOS 5 and trying to download apps/updates. Occasionally I get the "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" message and my downloads cancel. The iTunes store loads, all my Apple ID services work, I can view app descriptions on the App store, but when I go to download or update, I get this message.

Sometimes it's intermittent, but I've gotten it every time I tried for a week now. This also happened the day after I got my iPad; in that case I had to do a factory reset of the iPad's settings.

Resetting to factory settings (not resetting data) didn't help at all this time. However downloading updates over my phone's mobile tehering *does work* so it's some combination of my home **wifi and iPad settings.** I reset my cable modem and wireless router to no avail however.

What else can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What seems to work is signing out from my Apple ID (using the Apple ID link at the bottom of the App Store), then shutting off the device (hold the power button). Then I turn back on the device, go to the App store, enter my Apple ID info, and then try to download/update an app again.

Just restarting or relogging in to my Apple ID alone didn't seem to be enough.

Answer (score 0):

My iPad has been doing this as well. I'm not sure what the cause of it is, but it seems to go away for a little while if you:

> 1. Open the multitasking menu by double tapping the home button.
> 2. Close the App Store app by pressing and holding down the icon and pressing the red line
> 3. Re open the the App Store app and keep plugging along.

Again, not sure why it's doing this. I've tried [restoring](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1414) the iPad and it doesn't really fix it. Perhaps a software update will come along soon.

Comment: Are you on the latest iOS 5 as well?

Comment: Sure am. Just got in the mail yesterday.

Comment: Huh, I tried killing the app store app, restarting and even a different wireless network didn't work this time, nor did a complete reset.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to a missbehaving wifi/data connection which cause interruptions in communication. You could check signal level or even try to turn off and on your wifi/data connection. Also, you could try to download smaller chunks (ie not update all apps at once) and hope they get done before next interruption.

Comment: I've turned off the iPad 3 times now in this resent episode to no effect

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem... Recently I have paired my phone with my laptop through bluetooth.. After pairing I found that I cannot connect to itune store while updating.

So what I did is that went to bluetooth option and removed the paired laptop device from my list.

Now I can connect to itune store with my phone while updating..

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your firewall? This seemed to fix my connection problem pretty quick... http://howtofixstuff.blogspot.ca/2013/09/how-to-fix-cannot-connect-to-itunes.html

Comment: Can you summarize the information contained in the link so that your answer can stand alone?